# How can i delete ms access query object using DoCmd.DeleteObject

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to export a table by using a query and then i want to delete that query object from ms access file, but it gives me error - Cannot Update Database.File may be readonly.

My code below

```
MsAcs.OpenCurrentDatabase(newdb,false,"");
 MsAcs.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
                        MsAcs.DoCmd.TransferText(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcTextTransferType.acExportDelim, Type.Missing, "tmpExport", csvfile, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

MsAcs.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcObjectType, "tmpExport");
```

Gives Error

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 2):

[DeleteObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197376.aspx) expects a constant from the `AcObjectType` enumeration.
Instead of the full enumeration (`AcObjectType)`, use `AcObjectType.acQuery` as the first argument to `DeleteObject`, and the name of your query as the second argument.

From within an Access application session, I can delete a query named *tmpExport* with either of these 2 methods:

```vb
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "tmpExport"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpExport"
```

However, for either of those to work, the db must be updatable, not read-only.  So when those methods work, `Debug.Print CurrentDb.Updatable` replies `True`.

If I open the database read-only, `CurrentDb.Updatable` replies `False`, and either attempt to delete *tmpExport* throws error 3027, *"Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only."*

Unfortunately I don't know how to translate those statements to c#.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my code but it gives error when i pass on the arguments like below
MsAcs.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acQuery, "tmpExport");

Comment: no it doesn't work.. i'm still getting Cannot update. Database or object is read-only. after using MsAcs.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acQuery, "tmpExport");

Comment: Is it read-only?  I assumed you created *tmpExport* from earlier code, and now you want to delete it.  But what's actually going on?

Comment: No its not as i have checked the file properties.I'm working on export a ms access file to XLSX, so created MDB file and exporting a Table using query.Deleting the query object and then save the csv as xlsx.

Comment: Where does *tmpExport* come from?  Does it exist in the MDB file before you open the db file with your c# code, or does your c# code create *tmpExport*?

Comment: What does c# see as the value of `MsAcs.CurrentDB.Updatable` ?

Comment: It already exists in a mdb file, i create copy of it and create several mdb using it..

Comment: i'm not able to code MsAcs.CurrentDB.Updatable as when i try to wrtie MsAcs.CurrentDB - it refer to DAO Application class and not further extended. and Access.ApplicationClass MsAcs is my object..

Answer (score 0):

Both of these work for me:

```
using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
<...>
   MsAcs.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acQuery, "query1");
```

And drop table, yes, it is a query, nonetheless, drop table.

```
   MsAcs.CurrentDb().Execute("DROP TABLE query2");  
   MsAcs.Quit();
```

Make sure you have no databases in task manager running from previous testing.

Comment: DELETEOBJECT does not work at all, gives me Read Only Error and CurrentDB().Execute() - method belong to DAO..which is deprecated a long ago..

Comment: Jet DAO may be deprecated, ACE DAO is alive and on version 15, which comes with MS Access 2013. The library is `Microsoft Office x.x Access Database Engine Object Library` When you use Access Interop, you are using DAO ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57(v=vs.100).aspx )

Comment: Can you delete any object? Can you update any table? Have you got full permissions on the Access file and the folder in which it resides?